# Is it possible to instantiate Java compiler using JRE as Standard VM?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I'm trying to compile and load java class dynamically using reflection. My code works fine without any exceptions if I use JDK as Standard VM. but same code throwing Null Pointer Exception at `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` when I use JRE as Standard VM.

I can't have JDK in my class path. So, do we have any option to compile java code by using JRE as Standard VM? can anyone please assist me about this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The java-compiler API works only if a compiler is present. The compiler is present when you use a JDK, but not (typically) present when you use a JRE.

Were you intending to use a special compiler, one that differs from the one provided in the JDK? It looks like there's a way to plug-in third party compilers into the JRE.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html